# Profile query returns 0 rows

Tags: android, profile

I'm using ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI to attempt to get the user's profile info.  It runs but returns zero rows.

I suspect this is a permissions problem where the permission I'm setting for my app is not being seen by the provider.  I have (among other permissions):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
```

I've tried removing both of these permissions and I don't get any error (or any returned rows).  I've also tried misspelling the 2nd one.  Same thing.

Here's the code that does the query:

```
  private void fetchProfile ()
  {
    logD ("EA profiles:");  // wrapper on Log.d()
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath (ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

    final String[] projection = 
    {
      ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,                       // 0
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DISPLAY_NAME, // 1
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,      // 2
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,   // 3
    };

    String where = ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ?";
    final String args[] = {
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
    };
    String order = ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC";

    Cursor cursor = cr.query (uri, projection, where, args, order);
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
      long id = cursor.getLong(0);
      String name = cursor.getString(1);
      String addr = cursor.getString(2);
      int isPrimary = cursor.getInt(3);
      logD ("  id " + id + ", name " + name + ", addr " + addr + ", isP " + isPrimary);
    }
    cursor.close();
  }
```

I've tried this on three different Android devices.  Same behaviors.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: is the problem solved? I am also having same problem and struggling for the solution.

Comment: Maybe.  I need to do some more experimenting and maybe you can corroborate this.  I think the profile is defined only if the user specifically enters a profile.  On one of my phones, you can do this by opening the Contacts app and then clicking on "set up my profile".  Let me know whether this affects your results.

Comment: Even though the profile is setup on device, the query returns 0 rows (on some devices only). I am using https://github.com/jehy/Android-GetOwnerInfo/blob/master/Android-get-owner-contact-info.java to get the details and so far it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Uri as described in the [Accessing Contacts Data / Retrieve Contact Details](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html):

instead of:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath (
       ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
       ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    // uri == content://com.android.contacts/profile/data
```

use:

```
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
    // uri == content://com.android.contacts/data
```